# На английской версии сайта изменить некоторые данные, как сделать?

Tags: php, wordpress

https://www.hdwahl.de/
https://www.hdwahl.de/en/

Имеется сайт на Немецком языке и на Английском. При поиске показывает только немецкую надпись того, что ищем. Нужно, чтобы когда человек перешел на английскую версию сайта, то тоже изменилась надпись (приложу в фото). Также изменить надпись на кнопке. Скриншоты предоставил. Спасибо за помощь.

Еще в коде нашел данные строки которые отвечают за это. (скриншот есть)

[image: поиск на сайте]
[image: ссылка на поиск в сайте]
[image: скриншот из phpstorm]

Comment: Забыл дописать что надпись "Presse Du suchtest nach:" нужно изменить в английской версии сайта на "You are looking for:"
А кнопку "zur seite" на "more"

Comment: Так измените вопрос.

Comment: строки локаизации добавьте соответствующие в файлы локализаций

Comment: Я написал сюда так как не разбираюсь в php. И хотел бы пинок под зад, хоть в каком направлении мне идти.

Comment: если `_e()` за перевод отвечает, конечно

Comment: ищите файлы локализаций что нить а-ля `locale\en_EN\qode.po` и добавляйте туда строки в соответствующем формате а-ля `msgid "zur seite"` и `msgstr "more"`. Что касается локализации первой строки, ее обернуть в `_e()` и тоже добавить в файл. Какой конкретно формат локализации используется я хз. Возможно это и в админке настраивается вообще. Но вторую строку все равно придется обернуть в `_e()`

Comment: Достаточно правильно настроить неизвестный нам плагин мультиязычости. А при необходимости внести изменения в дочернюю тему.

Comment: Плагин использую WMPL

Comment: Вот о плагине нужно писать в вопросе. И код, кстати, нужно показывать кодом, а не скриншотами. Отредактируй вопрос.

Comment: Опять закрыватели активизировались. Ну и кто тут усмотрел "учебное задание"? И на каком основании? )))

Comment: Не понял. Что от меня требуется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код, который требует перевода, должен быть выведен через функции [gettext](https://wp-kama.ru/function-cat/lokalizatsiya). Например:

```
<?php echo esc_html__( 'Presse Du suchtest nach:', 'text-domain' );
```

Тогда через WPML String Translation вы сможете редактировать переводы 'Presse Du suchtest nach:'. Надо один раз открыть страницу с таким выводом, чтобы WPML занёс строку в базу.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Так и сделал. Все получилось

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.